# mocute 053 - can't use on windows

Tags: controllers, windows-7

I have a mocute 053 bluetooth game controller. I successfully connected it to my windows 7 PC but I can't use it in any game. I tried connecting it to overwatch and battlegrounds. when I move the stick on the controller nothing happens. How can I configure it?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You can try the "JoyToKey". Good Luck!

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please make sure you explain answers in details. Just links or recommending something without explanation doesn't help anyone.